# Review queues pulldown - numbers or circles? What now?

Tags: discussion, review

I think since a few days that the pulldown menu for review queues is now using dots instead of number of entries (grey dot: stuff to review. red dot: much more stuff to review. no dot: nothing to review).

But I am like 99% convinced that yesterday (or so) ... the pulldown did show me *numbers* again.

Is that feature still under work?

And for the record: it is not documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was mentioned in the following questions on Meta Stack Overflow:

- [When I look at the review icon, I see red](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355233/4751173)
- [The new review icon isn't an improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355236/4751173)

It looks like it's being A/B-tested (AFAIK there's no official confirmation of that, but no denial either), and for the moment only on Stack Overflow (because that's the only site with the new topbar).